# Change two rows background color on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have quite a few rows of data in a table and I'm trying to see if it's possible to highlight two rows at the same time on mouse over.

I can do something like

`<tr onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='#aaaaaa';" onmouseout="this.style.backgroundColor='#bbbbbb';">`

which works great for one row at a time but the data being shown is "paired" like below. Rows 1 and 2, 3 and 4. So I'm looking to see if I can highlight rows 1 and 2 at the same time when I mouse-over in either rows area. Then the same for 3 and 4.

`<tr><td>Row1</td></tr>`
`<tr><td>Row2</td></tr>`

`<tr><td>Row3</td></tr>`
`<tr><td>Row4</td></tr>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `<tbody>` tags to group the pairs of rows together, along with a CSS `:hover` style to set the color.

```
<html>
    <style>
        .foo:hover { background-color: #aaaaaa; }
    </style>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tbody class="foo">
                <tr><td>Row1</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Row2</td></tr>
            </tbody>
            <tbody class="foo">
                <tr><td>Row3</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Row4</td></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This does not work!  [`tbody` is only spottily supported](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/tbody).  [Try visiting this code](http://jsbin.com/odiga5) in Firefox, for example.